# How to make HTML5 video fade in when it has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I'm trying to have my HTML5 video element fade in when it loads, (I'm currently having it appear using Javascript `canplaythrough` as you can see in the code you see below, but it's a little harsh.) How can I get the HTML5 video element to fade in gently? I'm OK with JavaScript or jquery, but I don't know either one very well, so some complete code would be very helpful!

Here's the code: (if you run the code with the Run Code Snippet, it doesn't work well, so I highly suggest to go to my website, it's on is my video page here and works if you wait a 30 seconds/minute (until the video loads): [jeffarries.com/videos](http://www.jeffarries.com/videos).

```js
<script>
var e = document.getElementById("myVideo");
e.style.display = 'none'

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("myVideo");
       e.style.display = 'block'
};

</script>
```

```html
<video style="display: block;" id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="http://www.jeffarries.com/videos/jeff_arries_productions_intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Thanks for you time and effort!

Comment: And did you try just `$("#myVideo").fadeIn()`

Comment: I replaced `var e = document.getElementById("myVideo");
       e.style.display = 'block'` with `$("#myVideo").fadeIn()` and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Should work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/m6ryk47L/

Comment: I did exactly what you have on the fiddle.  But if you go to my video page it doesn't work somehow!

Comment: You have to include jQuery `

Comment: How do I do that? Do I do it in the `script` tag?

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, you probably shouldn't include it just to fade in an element. Here's a plain JS solution you can use instead -> https://jsfiddle.net/m6ryk47L/1/

Comment: @adeneo It works now, thanks!!! I'm not using any jQuery yet so that was helpful.  But I figured out how if I ever need to!  Do you want to compile and post as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to fade in the video with javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById("myVideo");
e.style.opacity = 0;

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById('myVideo');
        fade(e);
    }, 5000);
};

function fade(element) {
    var op = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (op >= 1) clearInterval(timer);
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1 || 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/m6ryk47L/2/)

Comment: I'm assuming I edit the `50` at the end of the JavaScript to change the time of the fadein?

Comment: Yes, that would be the time for the interval, decrease it to get a faster animation

Comment: I've been messing around with it, and I've come to the conclusion that I need it to appear when the video is completely finished loading not just the `canplaythrough` as that is unreliable (the video has been showing up and then I play it and it gets stuck in the middle), is there a way to do that?

Comment: There's lots of different [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), but `canplaythrough` is usually the one you want to know when the video can be played through, but it makes some assumptions, such as guessing that the rest of the video can be loaded based on the current download rate etc. The only other thing I can think of, would be to check the videos `readyState`, something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/m6ryk47L/3/

Comment: Thanks for the ready state code! Tried using that with spotty results as well, I think I like `canplaythrough` better. Would you be willing to add a timer to the code so once it receives `canplaythrough` it waits 5 seconds and then executes?  I don't now JavaScript well, sorry!

Comment: GREAT, Thanks a lot!!!! I don't know if this is a Safari thing, but if I switch tabs while the video is loading (hidden) and switch back, the video shows immediately, and it's loaded at all, any advice?

Comment: I have no idea, modern browsers do stuff like halting the execution, pausing timers etc. when you leave the tab, and the behaviour can vary across browsers

Comment: Ok, I will do some more research! Thank you sooooo much for all you did!